# Div doesn't expand with text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a forum but the problem is that the div where the text goes doesn't expand in height when the text becomes to long for the div. Instead the text goes outside.

I also need the sidebar (with the userinformation) to expand with the text so it always has the same height as the text.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9stPU/1/

CSS:

```
.forumContent {
list-style-type: none;
background: #34495e;
letter-spacing: 1px;
width: 1170px;
margin: 0;
color: white;
margin-left: 50px;
}

.forumContent li {
padding: 5px 0 5px 10px;
margin-left: -40px;
min-height: 41px;
}

.forumContent li h3 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 14px;
}

.forumContent li small {
font-size: 9px;
}

.forumContent a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.forumContent li:hover {
background: #3E5368;
}

.forumContent a li {
float: left;
width: 366px;
}

.forumContent a li:first-child {
width: 100px;
}

.topicUser {
width: 150px;
float: left;
background: #000;
margin-left: -10px;
height: 100%;
}

.topicUser h3 {
margin-left: 2.5px !important;
}

.topicUser small {
position: absolute;
margin-top: -15px;
margin-left: 7.5px;
}

.topicUser p {
margin-top: 2px;
margin-left: 3px;
}

.topicContent {
width: 1060px;
float: right;
height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ADD :

```
.forumContent {
  ...
  overflow: hidden; /* ADD THIS */
}
```

This problem occurs because the height  of the container element `forumContent` is calculated automatically (if it is not specified) as the the sum of the height of **non** float elements. the height of float elements is not considerate.